# list index out of range error while iterating in list length

Tags: python, list, iteration

I have the following code, which sortings_list consist of 2 items like

```
sortings_list = ['code', 'name']


for i in xrange(0, len(sortings_list)):
        if sortings_list[i] == '-%s' % field:
            sortings_list.pop(i)
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are removing items from a list while iterating, if you remove the first item then the second item's index *changes*. Use a list comprehension instead:

```
sortings_list = [elem for elem in sortings_list if not elem == '-%s' % field]
```

Answer (score 1):

You're calling pop() on the first item which removes it, and now the list only has one element.

Then you try to iterate to the second item, which doesn't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You are better off using list comprehension because indexing is messy. With Python, you don't need to index a list in most cases. That being said, if you still insist on using your solution:

```
for i in xrange(len(sortings_list) - 1, -1, -1):
    if ...:
        sortings_list.pop(i)
```

That is, you start from the end of the list and traverse backward. That way, all the indexing still works. Again, I highly recommend against doing things this way. Go with list comprehension which Martijn Pieters offers.